# Como posso saber se um ItemTapped foi clicado?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Tenho um `ListView` com uma função para que a cada 30 segundos o `ListView` seja atualizado.

Quando é acionado o clique em cima de um item do meu `ListView` outra tela nesse momento é chamada e infelizmente a tela do `ListView` ainda continua sendo atualizada a cada 30 segundos, gostaria de que nesse momento essa atualização de 30 em 30 segundos parasse. Eu poderia resolver isso com um ´if´, mas para isso preciso saber quando o `ItemTapped` foi acionado, o que não sei implementar.

Minha ListView:

```
<!-- Listagem de Produtos -->
<ListView x:Name="lstLeilao" 
          ItemTapped="OnTapLance">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- DataTemplate  = exibe dados de uma coleção de objetos em um ListView -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                ... 

                <!-- Grid de exibição -->

                ...
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

A função que conta 30 segundos:

```
//A cada 30 segundos atualiza a tela Leilão Aberto
public void TempoAtualiza()
{
    Device.StartTimer ( TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () =>
        {
            if (OnTapLance == true) //AQUI QUE EU IMPLEMENTARIA A FUNÇÃO
                return false;

            AtualizaDados(usuario);
            return true;
        });
}
```

A função de clique:

```
//Toque
public void OnTapLance(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    isLoading = true;
    var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as LeilaoObjeto;

    Navigation.PushAsync(new Lance(Convert.ToInt32(item.ID_LEILAO)));
    isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: Amigo a sua pergunta está muito confusa. Atenção ao seu if que apenas tem um `=`, se quer comparar valores tem de colocar  `if (ItemTapped == true) `. Mas visto que está a comparar com verdadeiro (true) também pode colocar `if (ItemTapped)`

Comment: Na verdade o ´if´ é apenas um exemplo, não é um código funcional. O ´ItemTapped´ é um evento que é acionado quando se toca em cima do item no ListView, preciso saber se alguém tocou ou não em algum item do ListView, isso que minha pergunta quer dizer.

Comment: Para facilitar então @IazyFox eu tirei o exemplo e coloquei a aplicação real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para sua função recorrente, que `AtualizaDados`, você está usando o recurso `Device.StartTimer`. Pelo que dá para ver no seu código, você já entende que essa função se repetirá enquanto a função retornar `true`.

Não ficou claro que você quer que essa função seja interrompida somente enquanto o usuário entra na tela de `Lance` ou se uma vez que um item foi selecionado a lista não seria mais atualizada, então vou mostrar como pode ser feito para os dois casos.

#### Pausando a atualização enquanto a nova tela foi aberta

Primeiramente vamos colocar uma variável externa à função do `StartTimer` e usá-la como parâmetro de retorno:

```
bool someItemTapped = false;

...

//A cada 30 segundos atualiza a tela Leilão Aberto
public void TempoAtualiza()
{
    Device.StartTimer ( TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () =>
        {
            if (!someItemTapped)
                AtualizaDados(usuario);

            return someItemTapped;
        });
}
```

Em seguida, ao acionar o evento `OnItemTapped`, você atribui um valor à variável `someItemTapped`:

```
//Toque
public void OnTapLance(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    someItemTapped = true;
    isLoading = true;
    var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as LeilaoObjeto;

    Navigation.PushAsync(new Lance(Convert.ToInt32(item.ID_LEILAO)));
    isLoading = false;
}
```

**Esse último passo você só precisa implementar se quisar usar com o efeito de pausa. Se for só para interromper a atualização após o clique, não precisa.***

Por último, vamos ajustar como você inicializa a função de timer. Não sei bem onde você a chama, mas deve ser no construtor. Para que funcione com o efeito de pausa, você precisaria iniciá-la a cada vez que a página for exibida, ou seja, no `OnAppearing`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    if(someItemTapped)
    {
        someItemTapped = false;

        // Inicializa a função recorrente
        TempoAtualiza();
    }

    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Podemos criar um `Timer` customizado e nele iremos ter um `CancellationTokenSource`, onde iremos registrar nosso evento para cancelar o nosso temporizador que atualiza os dados com o método `AtualizaDados`.

Primeiramente iremos criar o nosso `Timer` customizado. Crie a seguinte classe abaixo:

```
public class CustomTimer
{
    //Objeto que irá representar nosso temporizador, ele irá gravar todas nossas informações de tempo de execução do processo
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeSpan;
    //Delegate que irá conter a nossa função que desejamos que seja executada no nosso temporizador.
    private readonly Action _callback;
    //Token para cancelar o temporizador quando desejado
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;

    /// <summary>
    /// Construtor da temporizador customizado, aqui precisamos passar as informações de tempo e o método que será executado
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeSpan">Passar um TimeSpan com as configurações de tempo</param>
    /// <param name="callback">Passar o método que será executado</param>
    public CustomTimer(TimeSpan timeSpan, Action callback)
    {
        _timeSpan = timeSpan;
        _callback = callback;
        _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = _cancellation;

        Device.StartTimer(_timeSpan, () =>
        {
            //Quando o token de cancelamento for acionado iremos parar o processamento do timer
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return false;

            //Invoca o método que desejamos executar
            _callback.Invoke();

            return true;
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        //Registramos a intenção de parar o timer no token de cancelamento
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _cancellation, new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();
    }
}
```

Agora que temos nosso timer customizado, precisamos criá-lo como um atributo da classe para utilizarmos em dois pontos diferentes, depois mandaremos executar nosso temporizador no seu método `TempoAtualiza()`:

```
private CustomTimer _timer;

public void TempoAtualiza()
{
    _timer = new CustomTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () => 
    { 
        AtualizaDados(usuario);
    });

    _timer.Start();
}
```

Nesse momento temos nosso temporizador executando de 30 em 30 segundos, agora precisamos cancelar a execução quando clicarmos no seu `ListView`, para isso utilizaremos o método `OnTapLance` que você já tem criado:

```
public void OnTapLance(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    isLoading = true;
    var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as LeilaoObjeto;

    //Se o timer já foi instanciado e está sendo executado, iremos executar o método que para a execução.
    if (_timer != null)
        _timer.Stop();

    Navigation.PushAsync(new Lance(Convert.ToInt32(item.ID_LEILAO)));
    isLoading = false;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu nao tenho muita informação sobre o seu projecto mas este exemplo pode ajudar

> xaml

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                  VerticalOptions="Fill"
                  x:Name="ListviewOrder">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ImageCell
                  ImageSource="MyImage"
                  Text="{Binding OrderName}"
                  Detail="{Binding OrderNo}">
                <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                  <b:BehaviorCollection>
                    <b:EventToCommand CommandNameContext="{b:RelativeContext Details}"
                                      EventName="Tapped"
                                      CommandName="SelectCommand"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                  </b:BehaviorCollection>
                </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
              </ImageCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

> c#

```
   public ListView()
    {
        this.ItemTapped += this.OnItemTapped;
    }


    public ICommand ItemClickCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(ItemClickCommandProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemClickCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item != null && this.ItemClickCommand != null && this.ItemClickCommand.CanExecute(e))
        {
            this.ItemClickCommand.Execute(e.Item);
            this.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
```

Mas no fundo seria através do evento **OnItemTapped**

Posso ainda acrescentar este outro exemplo

```
listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>
{
await DisplayAlert("Tapped", e.Item.ToString() + " was selected.", "OK");
};

listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
{
await DisplayAlert("Selected", e.SelectedItem.ToString()+ " was selected.", "OK");
}
```

Continua a tratar-se de eventos neste caro o **ItemTapped** e o **ItemSelected**

Quando ocorrerem eles disparam uma mensagem no ecra.

Comment: Tirei o exemplo que estava para colocar minha aplicação real já que facilita, mas agradeço pelos exemplos.